# Simplifying some square numbers expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

I need help to fix theese out. Thank you.

$ \frac { \frac {1} {\sqrt {3} } - \sqrt {12} } { \sqrt {3} } $

---

$ \frac { \sqrt {x} } {\sqrt[3] {3} } + \frac {\sqrt[4] {x}} {\sqrt {x} } $

---

$ \sqrt {5} - \sqrt {3} = n \Rightarrow \sqrt {5} + \sqrt {3} = ? $

Comment: $$\frac { \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 3 }  } -\sqrt { 12 }  }{ \sqrt { 3 }  } =\frac { \frac { 1-\sqrt { 36 }  }{ \sqrt { 3 }  }  }{ \sqrt { 3 }  } =\frac { 1-6 }{ { \left( \sqrt { 3 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } =-\frac { 5 }{ 3 } $$

Comment: Thank you but it is not the correct answer of second expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac { \frac {1} {\sqrt {3} } - \sqrt {12} } { \sqrt {3} } = \frac { -\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}} } { \sqrt {3} } = \frac { -5 } { \sqrt{3}\sqrt {3} } = \frac { -5 } { (\sqrt{3})^2 } =  \frac { -5 } { 3 } = -\frac { 5 } { 3 }  $$

---

$$ \frac { \sqrt {x} } {\sqrt[3] {3} } + \frac {\sqrt[4] {x}} {\sqrt {x} } =$$
$$ \frac { \sqrt {x} } {\sqrt[3] {3} } + x^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}} =$$
$$ \frac { \sqrt {x} } {\sqrt[3] {3} } + x^{-\frac{1}{4}} =$$
$$ \frac { \sqrt {x} } {\sqrt[3] {3} } + \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}$$

---

$$ \sqrt {5} - \sqrt {3} = n \Longleftrightarrow$$ 
$$\left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)= n\cdot \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3} = \frac{2}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for first and third questions but the answer of the second question is: $\sqrt[6]{x} + (\sqrt[4]{x^3} / x)$ I didn't understand how

Answer (score 1):

If $$\left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}\right) = n\;,$$ Then $$\left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)= n\cdot \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}\right) = \frac{2}{n}$$